# Validation Rule for Changed Value

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

I'm working on a validation rule that looks at a certain field to see if the Prior Value of that field contains ".com".  The requirement is that users should not be able to change a picklist value if the previous value was an email address that ends in ".com".

The validation rule I created is CONTAINS(PRIORVALUE(Origin), '.com') but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas on why this wouldn't catch the ".com" in the picklist value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field is a picklist field you will want to convert it to text first to see if it contains a value:

```
CONTAINS( TEXT( PRIORVALUE( Origin ) ) , ".com")
```